# MySql subquery value doesnt show the correct result

Tags: mysql, subquery

How do I rewrite this query to show the correct value for the sub query `claims` if there isn't any record in listings for this account_id, but there is 1 record in `claimed_listings`. Thanks!

```
SELECT status, (SELECT count(id) 
               FROM claimed_listings 
               WHERE account_id = 1) AS claims  
FROM listings 
WHERE account_id = 1
```

I'm expecting to see a result like

```
status | claims
     A | 1
     F | 1
     E | 1
```

in this case there are three listings and 1 claim listing. 
Problem is if there is no listing(s) and 1 claim listing i get no results at all?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT a.Account_ID, Count(b.Account_ID) TotalAcount
FROM claimed_Listings a LEFT JOIN listings b
        on a.account_ID = b.Account_ID
WHERE a.Account_ID = 1
GROUP BY a.Account_ID
```

Comment: i will update my answer. Can you include your schema of your tables?

Comment: @gus in this answer replace "RIGHT JOIN Claim_Listings b" with "RIGHT JOIN claimed_listings b" then it should work.

Comment: @gus does it works now? you could change `ID` to any field you want.

Comment: BTW im not after the account_id. Im after claims and status so this query is totally incorrect.

Comment: I know becuase you are not giving us the schema. I'm showing you the possibility of the query. That's why I told you that you could change the field that fits your need. Back to the result, according with you, since `STATUS` is on the `listings` tables, what will be its value if there is no status, and 1 record on claimed listings? remember that you are joining the two tables using `Account_ID`.

Comment: I ended up making it 2 queries. Now it works either way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (hope I got you right..)

```
select count(cl.id), count(cl.account_id)
from claimed_listings cl
where cl.account_id=1 and cl.account_id not in (select account_id from listings)
group by cl.id
having count(cl.account_id) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not quite what im after. Say the user has 1 claim_listing but no listings, claim is shows nothing for some reason? If the user has a listing and a claim then it works? I could just split it into 2 queries if its not possible?

Comment: That returns Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables. Ive updated my question above if it helps any, thanks.